# How do I track dragging of a BrowserWindow in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an instance of a BrowserWindow. I would like to know when the window is being dragged/moved on the screen.

I have tried using the moved event but that event only gets fired after the window has been moved. It does not fire while the window is being dragged.

How do I track when the window is being dragged?

Comment: `moved` doesnt seem to trigger at all, whereas `move` seems to be the only one working??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it in another way.
I created a frameless BrowserWindow and I made my "system bar" with the icons that I want and the listeners that I want in the webpage loaded in this window.

This works fine and isn't expensive.

```
    let wX;
    let wY;
    let dragging = false;
    $('#systembar').mousedown(function (e) {
        ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'down')
        dragging = true;
        wX = e.pageX;
        wY = e.pageY;
    });

    $(window).mousemove(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (dragging) {
            var xLoc = e.screenX - wX;
            var yLoc = e.screenY - wY;

            try {
                remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().setPosition(xLoc, yLoc);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#systembar').mouseup(function () {
        dragging = false;
        ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'up')
    });
```

Comment: This is the most optimal solution so far

Answer (score 1):

The `move` (and `moved`) events of the `BrowserWindow` are emitted every time the window moves even a pixel. If the window is dragged and moved then the `move` event is continuously fired until the mouse stops.

When the `move` is detected you can get the position of the window as

```
let position = window.GetPosition();
let x = position[0];
let y = position[1];
```

Then use those positions as required

Comment: Maybe that is the case on other platforms but on Mac the `move`/`moved` events are only fired after the window has _stopped_ dragging.

Comment: I missed the note on how on Mac `move` is just an alias of `moved`

Answer (score 0):

The Electron API does not seem to offer tracking of the actual window position during a drag.

However, instead of trying to track the new position of the window itself, you could track the mouse cursor movement during mousedown in the draggable window area.

Code outline:

- Detect drag event
- Check if drag event within drag area bounds
- Track mouse cursor movement using the `mousemove` event

Answer (score 0):

You could run a loop constantly checking if the `window.screenX` or `window.screenY` values have changed. Something along the following:

```
function onScreenMove(cb) {

    var lastScreenX;
    var lastScreenY;

    function detectScreenMove() {
        if (lastScreenY !== window.screenY || lastScreenX !== window.screenX) {
            lastScreenY = window.screenY;
            lastScreenX = window.screenX;
            cb();
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(detectScreenMove);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(detectScreenMove);
}

onScreenMove(function() {
    // do something
});
```

To my knowledge, the process of reading the `screenX`/`screenY` values is not very expensive, so you wouldn't be killing the processor.

Unfortunately, `Object.observe()` has left Chrome as of v50, so there doesn't appear to be a more "under the hood" way of checking `window` property changes.

Comment: The solution works in theory but it might end up being quite expensive to constantly have a loop running